# Error in "getCovariate.corSpatial" with gamm function

Tags: r, correlation, spatial

I am trying to eliminate spatial autocorrelation using the gamm function using the following code:

```
model.data.cp.gamm.exp<-gamm(CP~s(YEAR), random=list(Ambience=~1), corSpatial(form=~Lat+Lon, type="exp", metric="euc"), data=data)
```

Sometimes I change the type to lin, rat, sph and gau.
However, for all cases, I keep getting the error:

```
Error in getCovariate.corSpatial(object, data = data) : cannot have zero distances in "corSpatial"
```

Although I have removed all duplicate coordinates within each year from my data, some are repeated over time and there is no way for me to change that. Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.